# How to improve Increasing Subsequences algorithm to incorporate un-sorted array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

I have been working on solving Increasing subsequence problem. The algorithm I came up with currently solves only for sorted arrays. I am writing my code in python 3.5. This problem is hosted on Leetcode.

In increasing subsequence problem, I am given an integer array, the task is to find all the different possible increasing subsequences of the given array, and the length of an increasing subsequence should be at least 2.

Example:

Input- [4,6,7,7]

Output - [[4,6],[4,7],[4,6,7],[4,6,7,7],[6,7],[6,7,7],[7,7],[4,7,7]]

Here is my working code for solving this question:

```
array = [4,6,7,7]

def incrSubseq(array): #Only works for sorted arrays.
    res = [[]]
    ans = []
    for num in array:
        res += [item + [num] for item in res if (item+[num] not in res)]
    for values in res:
        if len(values)>1:
            ans = ans + [values]
    print(ans)
incrSubseq(array)
```

How does this code work?

1. It starts by initializing a result variable `res` (a list of lists)
   which is initialized by an empty list.
2. Then I iterate through the given integer array `array` which is in sorted order, adding each element to the list, thus finding all the subsets of that can be formed. The `if` statement inside the list comprehension filters out the items that are duplicate and thus keeping only one copy of the list.
3. Then I filter all the array which has the length greater than 1.

Thus, solving the problem.

Now, what I am missing here is a way to solve for an unsorted array. As far as my understanding goes I need to put a check in a manner that when I am trying to add an element to `res` it should be greater than or equal to the item before it.

`res += [item + [num] for item in res if (item+[num] not in res) and (item <= num)]` which gives in empty lists.

Any suggestions on improving the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is completely correct! Just check if the last element in `item` was smaller than previous (maybe allow equal, depending on how one defined increasing).

So you add the check `item[-1] <= num` (with `-1` you get the last element of an array in Python).

Now there is one more problem. `item` could be empty and you would get an error. So you only want that `<=` check, if there is at least one element in `item`.
Below is a fancy solution using short circuiting of boolean operations where `(len(item) == 0 or item[-1] <= num)` is true when either there is no element (then the second check is *not* performed), or there is at least one element in `item` and you check if it is smaller or equal.

```
array = [4,6,3,7]

def incrSubseq(array): # Works for sorted arrays too :)
    res = [[]]

    for num in array:
        res += [item + [num] for item in res if (item + [num] not in res 
                                                 and (len(item) == 0 or item[-1] <= num))]

    return [values for values in res if len(values) > 1]

print(incrSubseq(array))
```

---

**[Short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)** means that a boolean expression is evaluated only until its final value can be determined. For example `False and 1/0` would not raise an exception because `and` is `False` if *any* of its two arguments is `False`. So when evaluation goes from left to right it will not calculate the `1/0`.

A bit more verbously the inner part of the above algorithm can be written as:

```
for num in array:
    for item in res:
        if item + [num] not in res:
            if len(item) == 0:
                # item is empty.
                res += [num]
            else:
                # item is not empty so we check its last element.
                if item[-1] <= num:
                    res += item + [num]
                else:
                    # We got something increasing here. Do not add.
                    pass
```

---

The **complexity** of this algorithm can be calculated as followed. Suppose the worst case input of `[1, 2, ..., n]`. Then in each step the number of resulting subsequences is doubled, resulting in `O(2^n)` subsequences and an output size of `O(n * 2^n)`. Every algorithm will take at least that long (if you are actually interested in outputting every sequence -- if you want generate everything on the fly aka. iterator and lazy evaluation style of functional languages it does not matter).

This algorithms takes much longer though. The main work we have to do for each subsequence in the output is to check if it would be a duplicate doing the naive `item + [num] not in res`. A comparison of two lists of length m takes `O(m)` worst case. And as considering the last `num` takes more than half of the total runtime we just use it as a good approximation here. This means the check of the  last `2^(n-1)` created subsequences takes `O(2^(n-1) * 2^(n-1) * n) = O(n * 4^n)` because you check every new sequence with every old. With a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) as a result datastructure this could be reduced to just `O(2^n)` as this checking if a new subsequence is valid just requires `O(1)`. Traversing the tree to actually write down all solutions requires then again `O(2^n * n)`.

Sidenote: If you like functional programming in python check out [syntax_sugar_python](https://github.com/czheo/syntax_sugar_python),

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about how `len(item) == 0` changes everything. I didn't quite get the short circuiting.

Comment: Also my code is not optimized. 
`array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]` would take a lot of time. Since I am generating all the subsets, it will be an exponential complexity code. O(n^n) I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)